# android scrollableTabs with fixed size

Tags: android

i have application that require more than five tabs i want to make scrolable tabs but when do it .tabs get smaller .i want all tabs to have the same size on the HorizontallScrollView
this is my .java class
    public class ScrolTabsDemoActivity extends TabActivity implements OnTabChangeListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

```
 TabHost tabHost;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);
      setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT); 

      this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

      Resources res = getResources(); 
        tabHost = getTabHost();

        tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
        TabHost.TabSpec spec;
        //Intent intent;

        Intent intent = new Intent().setClass(this, First.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("First").setIndicator(getString(R.string.shar_tab),res.getDrawable(R.drawable.eshtrkat_1))
                      .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        Intent intent1 = new Intent().setClass(this, Second.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Second").setIndicator(getString(R.string.wether_tab),res.getDrawable(R.drawable.mkal_1))
                      .setContent(intent1);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        Intent intent2 = new Intent().setClass(this, Third.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Third").setIndicator(getString(R.string.photo_tab),res.getDrawable(R.drawable.img_1))
                      .setContent(intent2);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        Intent intent3 = new Intent().setClass(this, Fourth.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Fourth").setIndicator(getString(R.string.book_tab),res.getDrawable(R.drawable.arshif_1))
                      .setContent(intent3);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);
        Intent intent4 = new Intent().setClass(this, Fivth.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Fivth").setIndicator(getString(R.string.main_tab),res.getDrawable(R.drawable.news_h))
                      .setContent(intent4);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);


        Intent intent5 = new Intent().setClass(this, Sixth.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Fivth").setIndicator("tab  6",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.eshtrkat_1))
                      .setContent(intent5);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        Intent intent6 = new Intent().setClass(this, Seven.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Fivth").setIndicator("tab  7",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.game_1))
                      .setContent(intent6);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);
        Intent intent7 = new Intent().setClass(this, Nine.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Fivth").setIndicator("tab  8",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.mkal_1))
                      .setContent(intent7);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        for(int i=0;i<tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++)
                       {
                       tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#234C09"));
                       }
                       tabHost.setCurrentTab(4);
                      // tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(4);
                       tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(4).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#6BE519"));
}

@Override
public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
    for(int i=0;i<tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++)
    {
        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#234C08"));
    }

    tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabHost.getCurrentTab()).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#6ADF17"));
```

}
}

i need some help

Answer (score 1):

I assume that an answer to this has probably been found but since this thread shows up when searching google I'm going to answer it anyway ;-)

While the idea of setting a fixed size in general is bad (you never know what size the text will be on other people's phones) I ran into this problem myself. To solve this add the following method to your TabActivity:

```
private void resizeTabs(TabWidget tabWidget){
    for(int i=0; i < tabWidget.getChildCount(); i++) {
        tabWidget.getChildAt(i).setLayoutParams(new 
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width, height)); 
    }
}
```

Then at the end of your OnCreate method call resizeTabs(tabHost.getTabwidget())